# Property of mutable type 'NSMutableDictionary' has 'copy' attribute; an immutable object will be stored instead

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, static-analysis

I am using Xcode9 and I tried to analyse the project.Then I got the following issue like

> Property of mutable type 'NSMutableDictionary' has 'copy' attribute;
>   an immutable object will be stored instead

Please go through the image shows the analyze issue

[image]

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: why you used `copy`

Comment: is it required "copy" ? any reason for using that ?

Comment: jak check the answer

Answer (score 3):

In Objective-C there is a copy method defined in `NSCopying` and other is `mutableCopy`, defined in `NSMutableCopying`. NSDictionary(superclass of NSMutableDictionary) conforms to both these protocols.

But in property accessors, only copy is available which uses copy method on `NSMutableDictionary` to create an immutable object, hence the warning when you run the static analyzer, because you are now trying to store an `NSDictionary` object into an `NSMutableDictionary` reference.

If you call any `NSMutableDictionary` method on this reference, I reckon the app should crash.

To solve this issue, you can either use strong that would hold the reference for you. But, if you really need a copy(for whatever reasons), you can write your own setter, something like this:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary *parameters;

- (void)setParameters:(NSMutableDictionary *)parameters {
    _parameters = [parameters mutableCopy];
}
```

Comment: then how should use can you add some example

Comment: appreciate bro.